# Log4j not writing to the development server

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Our application uses Log4J for its logging purposes.  I recently finished implementing and testing our Log4J capabilities on my local server in RAD 7.5.  The property settings for this are below.

```
# Set root category priority to INFO and its only appender to CONSOLE.
log4j.rootCategory= INFO, CONSOLE, rollingFile
#log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE, LOGFILE

# Set the enterprise logger category to FATAL and its only appender to CONSOLE.
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis.enterprise=INFO, CONSOLE, rollingFile

# CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=- %m%n

#rolling file storage - dp0jmr 07/24/2014
log4j.appender.rollingFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=C:\\applogs\\WPM\\wpmlog.log
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

With some careful fiddling, and adding in log calls to all the appropriate areas of our application, I managed to get the app generating log files in the specified location on my computer, c:\applogs\WPM\wpmlog.log.

On deploying this application to our development server, I've made the following change to one line of the above code.

```
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=/applogs/WPM/wpmlog.log
```

Note the changed directory at the end of this line.

This is the appropriate directory into which I want our application logs to be written.

However, when I go to this location in winscp after performing an action in the application that should write to the log, I find no wpmlog.log file at all.

I have not moved or altered the log files in any way other than to change the directory to which it should be writing.  I do not believe there is any problem with writing permission, because other applications on the same development server have no problems writing to their own log folders.  I have redeployed the EAR file more than once to no avail.

Comment: If you append the line `log4j.debug` in your file `log4j.properties`, do you see something useful in the defualt log files?

Comment: @PaulVargas I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but I've tried adding this as a line of text to my file, and it doesn't seem to help.  Unfortunately, this is part of a server update, so I have no idea where our System.Out statements might be writing to.